# Issue when selecting file directly through google drive using file_picker flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I am using [file_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker) for selecting a video directly through google drive. But the selected file could not be seen.

The video works fine when selected through phone's storage.

Have anyone encountered this issue before?

The code that I have used is below:

```
  void _pickPerformanceVideo() async {
    _fileSelectionNotifier.performanceVideoFileLoaderNotifier(true);
    try {
      _performanceVideoPath = (await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
        allowedExtensions: ['mp4', 'mov'],
        type: FileType.custom,
        allowMultiple: false,
        onFileLoading: (FilePickerStatus status) => print(status),
      ))
          ?.files;
      
      await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2));

      if (_performanceVideoPath != null) {
        int sizeInBytes = _performanceVideoPath!.first.size;
        double sizeInMb = sizeInBytes / (1024 * 1024);
        if (sizeInMb <= 0) {
          _performanceVideoPath = null;
          final snackBar = showSnackBar(strVideoSizeError2, 3,
              duration: Duration(microseconds: 3000));
          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
        } else if (sizeInMb > 250) {
          _performanceVideoPath = null;
          final snackBar = showSnackBar(strVideoSizeError, 3,
              duration: Duration(microseconds: 3000));
          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
        } else {
          _fileSelectionNotifier.performanceFileNotifier(true);
          _fileSelectionNotifier
              .performanceFileNameNotifier(_performanceVideoPath!.first.name);
          _fileSelectionNotifier.setPerformanceValidationValue(false);
        }
        _fileSelectionNotifier.performanceVideoFileLoaderNotifier(false);
      }
      print(_performanceVideoPath!.single.path);
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print('Unsupported operation' + e.toString());
      }
    } catch (e) {
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print(e.toString());
      }
    } finally {
      debugPrint("entered in finally block_performance vide");
      _fileSelectionNotifier.performanceVideoFileLoaderNotifier(false);
    }
  }
```

Comment: "But the selected file could not be seen" what do you mean by "seen"?

Comment: After selecting the video file, there is text to show the filename. If we are selecting the file through google drive, the filename is not getting displayed. It means the video is not detected by file picker.

Comment: do you have any code?

Comment: I have edited and added code in the question.